# Search tree and select items

Tags: autoit

Do you know how to scan a tree and select an item. For example is the autoit help file. I expand all the tree and what it has to do next is scan the items with a "history" in its name. If true, it has to select it and sleep for 5 seconds and continue select the next item it finds until end loop.

```
Global $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]", "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]")

$hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, "History",True)

_GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hWnd, $hItemFound)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's that easy:

```
#include <GuiTreeView.au3>

Global $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]", _
                                "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]")

$searchText = "History"
$hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText, True)
While $hItemFound
   _GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hWnd, $hItemFound)
   $next = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetNextVisible($hWnd, $hItemFound)
   $hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText, True, $next)
   Sleep(5000)
WEnd
```

By the way, you can use `_GUICtrlTreeView_GetNext(...)` instead for not only searching the visible next entry but the probably collapsed one as well. The `..._FindItem` will search for collapsed Items anyways.

And you'd probably want to use `_GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem(...)` in addition to `_GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem(...)` to get the proper action performed with a selection as well.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly :) Although `ClickItem` did not actually work/click the items? Anyways, I guess I'll still use SelectItem.

Comment: How about if it has to search texts with "History" AND "Win" at the same time? Do I have to use an array?

Comment: Just search for "History" only and then do an `If StringInStr(_GUICtrlTreeView_GetText($hWnd, $hItemFound), "Win") Then ... EndIf`.

Comment: And I just edited the answer above. You have to perform both, first the `...SelectItem(...)` and secondly the `...ClickItem(...)` for the action to be performed.

Comment: Oh Sorry. What I meant was if an item either has "Win" or "History", it will be selected, and not 2 root words in an item name. Example is Windows, WinAPI, History of something, etc.

Comment: That's easy as well. You just need to adapt the code from `_GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem(...)` in your `GuiTreeView.au3` which is located in your *Includes* folder in AutoIt. If you need help by doing so, it's probably best to ask a new question referring to these comments over here...