# Selecting more than one item in a tree

Tags: autoit

I have a code here that search and select item with a "Win" in its name. But I have to modify it to search items with either "Win", "History", "Credits" or "#" in its name and select it. Thanks!

```
_GUICtrlTreeView_Expand(ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]","", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]"),0, True)
Global $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]", "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]")
$searchText = "Win"
$hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText, True)

While $hItemFound   
   _GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hWnd, $hItemFound)
   $next = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetNextVisible($hWnd, $hItemFound)
   $hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText, True, $next)
   Sleep(1000)
WEnd
```

I also tried using `switch` but won't work:

```
Global $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]", "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]")
$searchText = "Autoit"
$hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText, True)
While $hItemFound   
   _GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hWnd, $hItemFound)
   $next = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetNextVisible($hWnd, $hItemFound)

   $foundWinItem = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, "Win", True,$next)
   $foundHistoryItem = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, "History", True,$next)

   Switch $next
   Case "Win"
      $hItemFound = $foundWinItem
   Case "History"
      $hItemFound = $foundHistoryItem
   EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware, but I'm one of a small handful of people who answer autoit questions on stack overflow. I'm also the one helping you right now on the autoit forums. Duplicating your question across the two is not going to get you anywhere. Be patient, and re-read my answer on the autoit forums as you've implemented it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, seems the index was not what you wanted to base it on like I'd previously thought, as the index is relative to the parent.

Instead just do the search manually. Here's a function I put together that just iterates over every item and checks it against a '|' separated list of strings.

```
#include <GUITreeview.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]", "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]")


For $it In _GUICtrlTreeView_FindAll($hWnd, "Win|History", True)
    _GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hWnd, $it)
Next

Func _GUICtrlTreeView_FindAll($hWnd, $sStrings, $fInStr = False)
    Local $aRet[1] = [0], $hItem

    Local $aStrings = StringSplit($sStrings, Opt("GUIDataSeparatorChar"), 3)

    While 1
        $hItem = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetNext($hWnd, $hItem)
        If $hItem = 0 Then ExitLoop

        $sText = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetText($hWnd, $hItem)

        For $s In $aStrings
            If ($fInStr And StringInStr($sText, $s)) Or $sText = $s Then
                _ArrayAdd($aRet, $hItem)
                $aRet[0] += 1

                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        Next
    WEnd

    Return $aRet
EndFunc   ;==>_GUICtrlTreeView_FindAll
```

Comment: @user2379805, works here. Does it very fast though (less than half a second to select all the items) so maybe you are missing it.

Comment: I put `Sleep` function but it still won't show that it actually selects the item. Should I use `clickItem`?

Comment: Did you put the `Sleep(555)` after `_GUICtrlTreeView_SelectItem($hWnd, $it)` in line 8? It works for me... Well, I have to open the AutoIt3.chm before...

Comment: And if you want to make it acutally select and open the entries, you have to use both functions, the `...SelectItem(...)` and the `...ClickItem(...)`.  Anyways, funny to see the solution of my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142503/search-tree-and-select-items/17149010#comment24887502_17149010) over here.

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer, I hadn't seen your comment. If I had I wouldn't have put the time I did put in to make that function. That would be 4 times he's asked the same question...